# Richfaces is not defined in richfaces 4.0.0.jar nested jsp(struts) and Jsf

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsf, richfaces

I am using JSF2.0 and I have the following RichFaces JAR files:

- richfaces-components-ui-4.0.0.Final.jar
- richfaces-components-api-4.0.0.Final.jar
- richfaces-core-api-4.0.0.Final.jar
- richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0.Final.jar

Facelets (XHTML) pages runs smoothly with `<rich:xxx>` tags. But when I embed `<rich:xxx>` tags in JSP pages, the following JavaScript error occues:

> Richfaces not defined.

Why does it occur in JSP pages and not in Facelets pages?

Answer (score 1):

The RichFaces JavaScript files are automatically included when you use the JSF2 `<h:head>` tag in your view. You've apparently used a `<head>` tag instead of `<h:head>` tag in your JSP view which caused that the RichFaces JavaScript files are not automatically included anymore.

Fix it accordingly.

```
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <html lang="en">
        <h:head> <!-- Here, you should use <h:head> instead of <head> -->
            ...
        </h:head>
        <h:body> <!-- And preferably also <h:body> instead of <body> -->
            ...
        </h:body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

Comment: Sorry I am using JSF 2.0 and want to embed with java server pages not faces(JSP) having scriplets tag like <%  out.println("Hello");%> .Till I am not getting any solution.Ok I ask u a question that if u a dummy.xhtml page of JSF 2.0 and want to include a jsp page dummy1.jsp having content-------------------------------------------------------------- <%  out.println("Hello");%> ----------------------------------------------------only How can u embed these two file either xhtml in jsp or jsp in xhtml.Waiting for solution.

Comment: I've read your comment 3 times and I still don't understand it. Please clarify. I can at least say that using *scriptlets* is a bad practice. Even more when you're already using a MVC framework like JSF. If you elaborate in detail why you need the *scriptlets*, then we will be able to answer you the right MVC approach to achieve the same.